# Calling a system call just before main

Tags: linux, linux-kernel

I am using Linux on x86-64. I need to insert a system call (essentially need a trap to OS) just before a user program starts executing its code (but after the loader/linker has mapped the libraries etc). Does anybody have a suggestion on what is the best way to achieve this **without** needing binary modification/recompilation?

Comment: Why do you want to do something like that without needing binary modification? For me that sounds like you want to create some tracking software for a software which you would then distribute and spy people... xD but please correct me if I'm wrong :)

Answer (score 2):

Use the LD_PRELOAD environment variable to load a custom library before libc, which will intercept the call to __libc_start_main which _start seems to use to begin the actual main() function.

Or use ptrace() to attach to the process like a debugger does.

Comment: I've been playing with this a bit.  If I define my own __libc_start_main() it is easy to get that called, and looking up the address of the original with dlsym and RTLD_NEXT seems to work, but so far I have not been able to either call the original or return.  I suspect this is because I've not found the proper function signature and so am corrupting the stack.  Finding the actual definition of this function in the eglibc sources is not proving easy.